# Window Phone 8 - Default Media player file url scheme

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to open the default Media Player in **Windows Phone 8**, from a browser's url, using some kind of scheme?
I would also like to know If there are other ways to open the media player from the browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing documented [on MSDN as a registered URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for the launching default media player.

[As per this MSDN page about file type associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if you try and link to a .MP3 or .AAC file or other audio or video file it will launch the media player and play the file you point to.

Also it states:

> Sometimes Internet Explorer overrides file associations: it launches the built-in media player to handle all music and video file types. Specifically, any file that has an audio/ or video/ content type. For example, your app can handle a (non-reserved) music and video file when it is launched from an email attachment. But if the same file is launched from Internet Explorer, the built-in media player will handle the file.